# overwrite trait of an included composer package to catch exceptions / ideas how to solve

Tags: laravel, oop, traits, overwrite

I'm using an external composer package inside my laravel based application.

I want to catch the the exceptions thrown from this package and log additional error details to these exceptions.

Exceptions are thrown inside a trait:

```
namespace Some\Package\File;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use Some\Package\Exceptions\CustomException;

trait SendHTTPRequests
{

    public function call(string $method, string $path, string $payload = '')
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->getClient()->request($method, $this->getCallableUrl($path, $query), [
                RequestOptions::BODY => $payload,
            ]);
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            $errorPayload = json_decode((string) $e->getResponse()->getBody(), true);

            throw new CustomException(
                $e->getMessage(),
                $errorPayload['code'] ?? 0,
                $errorPayload
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

As you can see the exceptions can be of type `ClientException` (Guzzle) or of `CustomException`, what's the best way to add additional data onto the message?

Should I override the trait OR should I include a custom "catch" inside the `register` method of `Handler.php` and throw an `OwnCustomException` for both and include my log logic into this `exception`?

I'm using this at the moment already for another customPackage I'm using:

```
    //catch all FTPpackage exceptions
    if ((new \ReflectionClass($e))->getNamespaceName() == 'FTPUploader\Exceptions')
        throw new \App\Exceptions\OwnFTPUploaderException($e);
```

But I'm confused on how to catch the exceptions of type `ClientException` since they are coming from guzzle directly, this will cause trouble for sure and I'm unsure how to solve this.

Which approach makes the most sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are thrown inside a trait, you can use the `getFile()` [method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getfile.php) on exceptions to know where they are from. In your `Handler.php` or where you are handling the exception, you could achieve what you want like this.

```
if ($exception instanceof RequestException && Str::contains($exception->getFile(), 'SendHTTPRequests')) {
    // do what ever you want.
}
```

I would catch all exceptions from guzzle from that file, this could clash if there is another class with the same name as the trait. You can include more of the namespace to make it more sturdy.